# Write the contents of a bibliography from thebibliography environment to a file

Tags: bibliographies, write

I need to write contents from `thebibliography` environment (BixTeX/BibLaTeX are not used) to an XML file. Each bibliographic source should be in a separate pair of `<reference>` and `</reference>` tags. Probably need to somehow redefine the `thebibliography` environment and/or the `\bibitem` command? I will be grateful for help.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

% I need to get a test.xml file containing
% <references>
% <reference>Papargyri-Beskou, S., Tsepoura, K., Polyzos, D. \& Beskos D. (2003). Bending and stability analysis of gradient elastic beams. \emph{Int. J. Solids Struct.}, \textbf{40}(2), 385--400. DOI 10.1016/S0020-7683(02)00522-X</reference>
% <reference>Niiranen, J., Balobanov, V., Kiendl, J. \& Hosseini, S. (2017). Variational formulations, model comparisons and numerical methods for Euler--Bernoulli micro-and nano-beam models. \emph{Math. Mech. Solids}, \textbf{24}(1), 312--335. DOI 10.1177/1081286517739669</reference>
% </references>

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{papa}
Papargyri-Beskou, S., Tsepoura, K., Polyzos, D. \& Beskos D. (2003). Bending and stability analysis of gradient elastic beams. \emph{Int. J. Solids Struct.}, \textbf{40}(2), 385--400. DOI 10.1016/S0020-7683(02)00522-X
\bibitem{niir}
Niiranen, J., Balobanov, V., Kiendl, J. \& Hosseini, S. (2017). Variational formulations, model comparisons and numerical methods for Euler--Bernoulli micro-and nano-beam models. \emph{Math. Mech. Solids}, \textbf{24}(1), 312--335. DOI 10.1177/1081286517739669
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be a find/replace task in your text editor or maybe an sed script

Comment: @DG' Thanks for comment. I do this now, but I want to automate it, because 1) I need to generate an XML file for each of 10-12 articles 2) before writing to the XML file, I need to normalize the text of bibliographic sources by clearing them of LaTeX commands and replacing them with the necessary ones tags using 5-7 different regular expressions. This is a routine job that can definitely be automated. But I don't understand how to get all the contents of `thebibliography` environment in some variable for some my function

Comment: @DG' But about using sed, thanks for the tip. I'm on macOS and didn't know about this console utility. It's just that I was already able to generate the XML file I needed using LaTeX, except for exporting bibliographic sources.

Comment: Maybe you should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to play with

Comment: @DG' Thanks for the advice. I made MWE but it is very simple. Now it's not so important for me what exactly will be written after each `\bibitem`.

Answer (score 1):

To make parsing a bit easier you can first convert the LaTeX source to HTML using TeXht. An additional advantage is that TeX4ht already performs some processing to handle LaTeX commands. In the terminal:

```
make4ht yourfile.tex
```

Snippet of resulting html file, showing the first reference:

```html
<div class='thebibliography'>
   <p class='bibitem'><span class='biblabel'>
 [1]<span class='bibsp'>   </span></span><a id='Xpapa'></a>Papargyri-Beskou, S., Tsepoura, K., Polyzos, D. &amp; Beskos D. (2003).
   Bending  and  stability  analysis  of  gradient  elastic  beams.  <span class='cmti-10'>Int.  J.  Solids
   </span><span class='cmti-10'>Struct.</span>, <span class='cmbx-10'>40</span>(2), 385–400. DOI 10.1016/S0020-7683(02)00522-X
   </p>
```

You can parse this with XPath to get the data out. As an example below a Bash shell script that uses `xmllint` as XPath parser, but of course you can choose any command line tool or library in a programming language to do the parsing.

Steps:

1. Run TeX4ht
2. Find the number of references using `count()` in XPath
3. For each reference extract the text

   - Skip `<span[class='biblabel']>` nodes as they are not part of the reference text
4. Remove newlines and double spaces using terminal tools `tr` and `sed`
5. Print tags around each reference and around the entire block

Code:

```bash
make4ht $1
htmlfile=`basename $1 .tex`
numberrefs=`xmllint --xpath "count(//p[@class='bibitem'])" $htmlfile.html`
echo "<references>"
for refnr in $(seq 1 $numberrefs); do
   reftext=`xmllint --xpath "(//p[@class='bibitem'])[$refnr]//text()[not(parent::span[@class='biblabel'])]" $htmlfile.html`
   reftextnb=`echo $reftext|tr '\n' ' '|sed -r -e 's/(\xC2\xA0| ){2,}/ /g'`
   echo "<reference>$reftextnb</reference>"
done
echo "</references>"
```

Run this script using the following terminal command:

```
bash myscript.sh mydocument.tex
```

Result:

```xml
<references>
<reference> Papargyri-Beskou, S., Tsepoura, K., Polyzos, D. &amp; Beskos D. (2003). Bending and stability analysis of gradient elastic beams. Int. J. Solids Struct. , 40 (2), 385–400. DOI 10.1016/S0020-7683(02)00522-X </reference>
<reference> Niiranen, J., Balobanov, V., Kiendl, J. &amp; Hosseini, S. (2017). Variational formulations, model comparisons and numerical methods for Euler–Bernoulli micro-and nano-beam models. Math. Mech. Solids , 24 (1), 312–335. DOI 10.1177/1081286517739669 </reference>
</references>
```

Note that for Mac maybe some flags and functionality of the Bash script and tools are different or not available.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried using various converters to HTML or XML when I started researching this problem (that is just converting to XML only meta-information from the article). Unfortunately my class (it's not the `article` class) uses a huge number of functions I wrote that compile fine in PdfLaTeX but in `tex4ht` I get a huge number of errors.

Comment: Therefore, I thought it would be more expedient to write XML tags to XML file using the usual TeX or LaTeX commands. I can also easily parse and write to the file the title of the article, the names of the authors, their affiliations, keywords, funding info, but not the bibliographic list. Unfortunately, I can't post here an observable MWE file with a full-text article and my class. I was hoping that it would be possible to save the contents of `thebibliography` environment to some variable, which I can then parse using regex.

Comment: But I'm currently looking into the possibilities of `sed` or `grep` to parse a `tex` file from a script that can be run via `\immediate\write18`.

Comment: @Crosfield since you are primarily interested in the contents of the `thebibliography` environment you could delete all LaTeX code before that environment (I presume that your custom functions are not used within the bibliography items) and then follow the approach of this answer.

Comment: Actually I started writing a macro that dumps the body of the bibliography to the terminal/to a file from within LaTeX by redefining the `thebibliography` environment, which did work, but the output was rather messy without a simple way of cleaning it up. Therefore I thought converting to html first was the better choice.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I don't want to delete anything from the file beforehand. However, the way to "cut" a piece out of the file using regex and parse it using part of your script seems to me a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: What did this "output was rather messy" look like? Is it a continuous stream of TeX tokens?